# How to get 2-Sat values

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, 2-satisfiability

Whenever I search for an algorithm for 2-Sat, I get back the algorithm for the decision form of the problem: Does there exist a legal set of values that satisfy all the clauses. However, that does not allow me to easily find a set of satisfying boolean values.

How can I efficiently find a legal set of values that will satisfy a 2-Sat instance?

I am working in c++ with the boost library and would appreciate code that can be easily integrated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a decision algorithm for detecting if there exists a valid assignment to 2-SAT, you can use that to actually find out the actual assignment.

First run 2-SAT decision algorithm on the whole expression. Assume it says there is a valid assignment.

Now if x_1 is a literal, Assign x_1 to be 0. Now compute the 2-SAT for the resulting expression (you will have to assign some other literals because of this, for instance if x_1 OR x_3 appears, you also need to set x_3 to 1).

If the resulting expresion is 2-Satisfiable, then you can take x_1 to be 0, else take x_1 to 1.

Now you can find this out about each literal.

For a more efficient algorithm, I would suggest you try using the implication graph approach.

You can find more info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-satisfiability

The relevant portion:

> a 2-satisfiability instance is
>   solvable if and only if every variable
>   of the instance belongs to a different
>   strongly connected component of the
>   implication graph than the negation of
>   the same variable. Since strongly
>   connected components may be found in
>   linear time by an algorithm based on
>   depth first search, the same linear
>   time bound applies as well to
>   2-satisfiability.

The literals in each strongly connected component are either all zero or all 1.

Answer (score 0):

There's at least one algorithm that lists all the solutions to a 2-sat problem, by Tomas Feder: http://www.springerlink.com/content/j582276p06276l12/

Comment: The paper you linked to shows how to solve network flow problems through repeated calls to 2-Sat

Comment: I haven't read the paper, but Wikipedia says it lists an algorithm: "Feder (1994) describes an algorithm for efficiently listing all solutions to a given 2-satisfiability instance, and for solving several related problems."

Comment: @user108088: The paper talks about solving 2Sat using network flow.